# why facebook meta og:image tag is not read properly

Tags: html, facebook

I am trying to have a share url feature on facebook. But facebook is not reading the og:image meta tag. It does read the title properly.

what is wrong?

I have put meta tags in head and no meta tag is in body.

Please provide help.

EDIT:

Based on ogp.me, I did include all the required tags but still FB is not reading og:image....please help what is missing??

http://www.itraintowin.com/video/kKU5romNuWg

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.itraintowin.com%2Fvideo%2FkKU5romNuWg

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- for Google -->
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />

<meta name="author" content="" />
<meta name="copyright" content="" />
<meta name="application-name" content="" />

<!-- for Facebook -->          
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />

<!-- for Twitter -->          
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
Fill the content =" ... " according to the content of your page
```

Comment: Check the page:
http://ogp.me/
in the examples there web pag
Also check the permissions on the folder where the image is hosted.
Clean the cookies and cache of your browser.
Facebook sometimes takes longer to read the new thumbnail, you could porbar another browser

Comment: I did add all 4 required attributes but did not help. Please check my link above. It does pick up images sometimes....but not consistently all the time